# I get an error when trying to install admob for my react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, admob

Here is my error

"/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAdExposureReporter.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VerbaWordgame-hjhnfkuavuuzyvazvbxuolysslhn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VerbaWordgame/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement' for architecture arm64"

I have tried so many things and put around 30 hours into figuring out why it doesn't work but i just can't get admob to function. I'm using the npm react-native-google-mobile-ads and have my project in visual studio code and use expo build to upload my projects. Has anyone met this problem?

I'm trying to install admob on my react native expo project but it doesn't work.

Comment: What happened when you followed the instructions given by the error?

Comment: Which of them? There are no clear instructions but i've searched around and tried pretty much every forum there is about it, always get the same error. A lot of the people that get this error use xcode, but this is an expo project so i use visual studio on pc

Answer (score 0):

You can use @react-native-firebase/admob for integrating the ads in your app. Install these 2 libraries "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^11.5.0", and "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0" and start integrating the ads. Keep in mind that the versions of firebase/admob and firebase/app are the same because the admob no longer receives updates if version mismatches then it won't work.

You can follow this guide
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-implement-admob-in-react-native-with-firebase/

It worked for me fine. Let me know if you have any questions.